compare loadtest vs wrk2?
I am looking for a command line HTTP load testing tool, able to control common parameters such as concurrency and throughput, and able to gather statistics about latency (response time), errors, etc.
I am considering two option:
https://github.com/alexfernandez/loadtest
and
https://github.com/giltene/wrk2
The two look very similar. In fact, I used the former in the past, and it worked well. Can someone explain what are the specific differences between the two, that may help me decide which one to use?
